Align Text in The Left Or Right
I am using online editor .NET Fiddle for a test purpose and trying to create space selecting multiple lines, specifically to align them all in the right or left. I've seen a person doing so, but not sure how he did that.
    string aa = "Hello World!";
    string bb = new string(aa.Reverse().ToArray());
            
Console.WriteLine(bb);  

I just want to align the above in the left alignment with a shortcut key, specifically the variables declared above. Is there any shortcut way doing so rather using spacebar for each line?

The tags really are completely irrelevant to this. Now that out of the way: Have you tried the "Tidy up" Button?

Yes, I checked that @Fildor. But the other person was using some kind of shortcut key to align rather than Tidy Up feature as he aligned them one by one like indenting.

And you cannot ask that person because ... ?  I just tried and I was totally able to indent by using Tab and Backspace but that also wasn't what that person was doing, right?

Worked man @Fildor. Sometimes this easy things get messed up, Thanks very much for this.

i can confirm (as someone who is working on .NET Fiddle) that we don't have specific keyboard shortuct to format the whole text block, so Tab and Tidy Up is the way to go :)
